# Confused - AppServiceProvider.php versus app.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, service-provider

Where do I specify my bindings exactly? It seems I can do it in either of these files.

**config/app.php**
Inside of `'providers' =>`

**app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**
Inside of `register()`

Comment: Totally valid question but thanks for the close vote

Comment: You register bindings in a service provider, and you load service providers via **config/app.php**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your bindings are not related to **App**, then I would create a new ServiceProvider class where I overwrite the *register* method with my new binding, then you have to let Laravel know that this class exists registering as a Provider in your *config/app.php* providers list, that is:

app/Providers/MyNewClassServiceProvider.php

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class MyNewClassServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
 public function register()
 {
    $this->app->bind(
        'App\Repository\MyNewClassInterface',
        'App\Repository\MyNewClassRepository'
    );
 }
}
```

config/app.php

```
'providers' => [
// Other Service Providers

'App\Providers\MyNewClassServiceProvider',
],
```

Answer (score 7):

The service providers array is loaded via `config/app.php`. This is the only actual place that providers are registered, and is where you should put *Service Providers*.

`AppServiceProvider` is for Laravel-specific services that you've overridden (or actually specified), such as the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar`, The HTTP/Console Kernels, and anything you wish to override in Laravel. This is a *single* service provider, that registers container bindings that you specify.

Really, you could load anything you want here, but there's a bunch of ready-to-go service providers in the `app/Providers` directory for you so you don't have to go and make one yourself.